# Why does the “TypeError: client.db is not a function” appear on Node.js and how do I fix it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lookup

I am writing mongodb aggreagation query in nodejs. I tried my best to figure it out, but the codes won't work in my method. I'm getting following error:TypeError: client.db is not a function

```
    const { MongoClient, ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
    
    async function main(){
    
        const uri = `mongodb://${dbUser}:${dbPassword}@${ipAddress}:${port}/${dbName}`;
    
        const client = new MongoClient(uri);
    
        try {
    
            await client.connect();
    
            await printStudents("541516516165164489d3aee");
    
        } finally {
            await client.close();
        }
    }
    
    main().catch(console.error);
    
    /**
     * Print the students for a given schoolId
     * @param {MongoClient} client A MongoClient that is connected to a cluster with the education database
     * @param {ObjectId} schoolId
     */
    
    async function printStudents(client,schoolId){
        const pipeline = [
            { 
                '$match' : { '_id' : ObjectId(schoolId) } 
            },
            {
              '$project': 
              {
                '_id':  { '$toString': '$_id'}
              }
            },
            {
                '$lookup':
                {
                    'from': 'students',
                    'localField': '_id',
                    'foreignField': 'schools',
                    'as': 'Students'
                }
            }
        ]; 
    
        const aggCursor = client.db("education").collection("schools").aggregate(pipeline);
    
        await aggCursor.forEach( err => {
            console.log(`${err._id}: ${err.$lookup}`);
        });
    }
```

I hope I get some good advice on how to tackle the problem properly. :)

Comment: You specified to which database to connect in your `uri`, so i think that you don't need to use `client.db(...)`

Comment: client and url, both scopes have ended there itself. Those variables arent accessible wher you want it.

Comment: No I deleted it because it is privacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a string as the first argument, which should be the mongo db client.

Change from :

```
     await printStudents("541516516165164489d3aee");
```

to :

```
 await printStudents(client,"541516516165164489d3aee");
```

Comment: If you find the answer is helpful, you can upvote or mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

When calling the `printStudents` method, you have not passed the client object as a parameter. By calling `printStudents("541516516165164489d3aee")`, the client parameter is a string and the schoolId parameter is undefined.
You should call `printStudents(client, "541516516165164489d3aee")` instead.